# postgresql sequence getting max_value

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence

How to get max_value and min_value Postgres sequence?

I created the sequence using this statement

```
create sequence seqtest increment 1 minvalue 0 maxvalue 20;
```

I tried this query `select max_value from seqtest` gives error

```
ERROR:  column "max_value" does not exist
LINE 1: select max_value from seqtest;
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "seqtest.last_value".
```

Output of `select * from seqtest`

```
test=# select * from seqtest;

-[ RECORD 1 ]-
last_value | 0
log_cnt    | 0
is_called  | f
```

Comment: postgres 10?.. I assume

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
t=# create sequence seqtest increment 1 minvalue 0 maxvalue 20;
CREATE SEQUENCE
t=# select * from pg_sequence where seqrelid = 'seqtest'::regclass;
 seqrelid | seqtypid | seqstart | seqincrement | seqmax | seqmin | seqcache | seqcycle
----------+----------+----------+--------------+--------+--------+----------+----------
    16479 |       20 |        0 |            1 |     20 |      0 |        1 | f
(1 row)
```

Postgres 10 introduced new catalog: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/catalog-pg-sequence.html

also:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-10.html

> **.** Move sequences' metadata fields into a new pg_sequence system catalog
>   (Peter Eisentraut)
>
> A sequence relation now stores only the fields that can be modified by
>   nextval(), that is last_value, log_cnt, and is_called. Other sequence
>   properties, such as the starting value and increment, are kept in a
>   corresponding row of the pg_sequence catalog.

Comment: select * from pg_sequences, with an 's', not pg_sequence. You'll get a lot more info.

Answer (score 3):

```
select min_value, max_value from pg_sequences where sequencename = 'seqtest';
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/view-pg-sequences.html

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, it can be achieved using psql prompt using the command
\d

```
postgres=# \d seqtest
                    Sequence "public.seqtest"
  Type  | Start | Minimum | Maximum | Increment | Cycles? | Cache 
--------+-------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+-------
 bigint |     0 |       0 |      20 |         1 | no      |     1
```

Answer (score 0):

But this query shows seqmax=9223372036854775807 (2^63-1) for any kind of sequence somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the psql tool you can use:

`\d <sequence_name>`

Example:

```
my_db=# \d hibernate_sequence
     Sequence "public.hibernate_sequence"
    Column     |  Type   |        Value
---------------+---------+---------------------
 sequence_name | name    | hibernate_sequence
 last_value    | bigint  | 6086596
 start_value   | bigint  | 1
 increment_by  | bigint  | 1
 max_value     | bigint  | 9223372036854775807
 min_value     | bigint  | 1
 cache_value   | bigint  | 1
 log_cnt       | bigint  | 32
 is_cycled     | boolean | f
 is_called     | boolean | t
```

The max value is in the response.